# can you define array size in class initialiser list

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initializer-list

is it at all possible in a reasonable way without hacks to define the size of an object array in a class without making the array size static. eg.

```
class Byte_Buffer
{
    Byte_Buffer(uint16_t bs) : buf_size(bs) {}

    const uint16_t buf_size;

    uint8_t storage[ buf_size ]; 
};
```

Comment: sorry should have mentioned if not obvious C++

Comment: seems to be the only answer i could find, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751878/determine-array-size-in-constructor-initializer

Answer (score 1):

template < int ARRAY_LEN > // you can even set to a default value here of C++'11

class MyClass
  {
  int array[ARRAY_LEN]; // Don't need to alloc or dealloc in structure!  Works like you imagine!
  }

// Then you set the length of each object where you declare the object, e.g.

MyClass<1024> instance; // But only works for constant values, i.e. known to compiler