# Declaring the array size with a non-constant variable

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

I always thought that when declaring an array in C++, the size has to be a constant integer value.

For instance:

```
int MyArray[5]; // correct
```

or

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 6;
int MyArray[ARRAY_SIZE]; // correct
```

but

```
int ArraySize = 5;
int MyArray[ArraySize]; // incorrect
```

Here is also what is explained in [The C++ Programming Language, by Bjarne Stroustrup](//www.stroustrup.com/3rd.html):

> The number of elements of the array, the array bound, must be a constant expression (§C.5). If you need variable bounds, use a vector(§3.7.1, §16.3). For example:
>
> ```
>   void f(int i) {
>       int v1[i];          // error : array size not a constant expression
>       vector<int> v2(i);  // ok
>   }
> ```

But to my big surprise, the code above does compile fine on my system!

Here is what I tried to compile using GCC v4.4.0:

```
void f(int i) {
    int v2[i];
}

int main() {
    int i = 3;
    int v1[i];
    f(5);
}
```

Success?!?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: And this is why testing something with a compiler doesn't mean anything in terms of code correctness.

Comment: Duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is [a GCC extension](//gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Length.html) to the standard:

You can use the `-pedantic` option to cause GCC to issue a warning, or `-std=c++98` to make in an error, when you use one of these extensions (in case portability is a concern).

Comment: Using `-std=c++98` doesn't help, that doesn't disable the extension. Use `-pedantic` for a warning or `-pedantic-errors` for an error

Answer (score 6):

You are using a feature from C99 which is called VLA(variable length arrays). It would be better if you compile your program like this:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++98 myprog.cpp
```

Comment: Why would that be better? It doesn't change anything.