# Constant expressions in array declarations

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr

[C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) says that

> Array dimension must be known at compile time, which means that the
>   dimension must be a constant expression

A separate point is made that

```
unsigned count = 42;           // not a constant expression
constexpr unsigned size = 42;  // a constant expression
```

I would, then expect for the following declaration to fail

```
a[count];                      // Is an error according to Primer
```

And yet, it does not. Compiles and runs fine.

What is also kind of strange is that `++count;` subsequent to array declaration also causes no issues.

Program compiled with `-std=c++11` flag on `g++4.71`

Why is that?

Comment: Are you compiling with all warnings? `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863347/declaring-the-array-size-with-a-non-constant-variable

Comment: Indeed `ISO C++ forbids variable length array` warning comes up. Not an error though. Please answer so i can accept

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed

Comment: @Jam, It's an error with `-Werror`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is *not* actually legal C++. Some compilers allow variable-length arrays as an extension, but it's not standard C++. To make GCC complain about this, pass `-pedantic`. In general, you should always pass at least these warning flags go GCC:

```
-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Comment: Isn't `-W` and `-Wextra` the same thing?

Comment: @JesseGood: Hm, maybe, I might not be up-to-date. Feel free to post something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

According to this link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html, GCC supports variable-length C arrays in C90 mode and in C++. Since it's not standard C++, you should treat this as a compiler extension and thus assume it's not portable.

Comment: would you know which gcc 4.x support VLAs ?  i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
seems not to

Comment: I'm not really sure when the feature was added.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already provide the solution, g++ allows variables length arrays (VLAs) as an extension in C++ (technically VLAs are a C feature from C90). To make sure that you are using standard conforming C++, pass `-pedantic` to get a warning and `-pedantic -Werror` to make the warning into a hard error.

I recommend the following when compiling in debug mode:

> g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
>   -Werror -Wconversion

`O0` is an [optimization flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and `-g3` is used for [debugging](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). These need to be changed when you want to use optimization and don't need debugging.
However, `-Werror -Wconversion` sometimes might need to be removed as you might not be able to change code for certain reasons, such as when using third party libraries. For a description of what each one does, refer [to here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).