# Array of non-constant size: Why does this even work?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size :";
    cin>>n;
    int array[n];  // I've worked some outputs and it works 
    return 0;
}
```

Is this some kind of dynamic allocation?
Why doesn't it even gives an error for 'n' to be a "const"?

Also, writing `cout << array[n+5];` doesn't result in an compile time or runtime error.

I'm using Dev-C++.

Comment: +1 for asking not why it doesn't work, but why it works when it shouldn't.

Comment: It's not dynamic. `n` `int`s are allocated on the stack, and they're deallocated at the end of the scope. It's not supported by the standard, but g++ permits it as an extension. Note also that it's allowed in C99.

Comment: Well this is not standard way to code, but it would be hard to come up with a compiler grammar to intentionally make it not work :P

Comment: @NiklasB. It works fine with `-std=c++11`. To disable GNU extensions must use `-pedantic` or better `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: here is some explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863347/declaring-the-array-size-with-a-non-constant-variable

Comment: @miushock grammar has nothing to do with it, it is not a syntax error, but it is a constraint violation (in C++ the expression inside the brackets must be constant). It would be easy for the compiler to issue an error, but the compiler developers chose to implement this extension.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It's definitely a pretty exact duplicate.

Comment: As for `cout<<array[n+5];`, C++ doesn't do bounds checking, so this doesn't automatically lead to an error. However, it's undefined behaviour so "anything can happen". Don't do it.

Comment: @Lucky -- Dev-C++ is not a compiler.  The compiler that Dev C++ uses is g++ (and a very old version).  Dev C++ is just an integrated environment so that it becomes easier to use the g++/gcc tools.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently one can declare variable length arrays in C99, and it seems [GCC accepts then for C++ also](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression.

You learn something every day .. I hadn't seen that before.