# Dynamic memory allocation in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, variable-length-array

Why does this work?

```
    #include <iostream>    

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        int arraySize;
        std::cin >> arraySize;

        int array[arraySize];

        for(int element : array)
        {
            element = 42;
            std::cout << element << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "Array size: " << sizeof(array) << "\n";
        std::cout << "Element count: " << sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

        return 0;
    }
```

My understanding of dynamic memory allocation in C++ tells me that one case where it is needed is when you do NOT know the amount of memory you need to allocate at compile-time. In this program, clearly the array size is not known when the program is compiled, but is dynamic, as it can change with the value the user enters.

Here is a program run after it is successfully compiled(warning and error free) with:
g++ program.cpp -std=c++11 -o program.exe

*Enter a number: 12

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

42

Array size: 48

Element count: 12*

As you can see, an array was created with a *user-defined* amount of elements,
each was successfully assigned to 42, and proven to exist with the sizeof() operator.

Why does this not count as dynamic memory allocation and compile?

Comment: This is not dynamic memory allocation. This is an extension to the C++ language by your compiler.

Comment: *int array[arraySize];* -- This is not valid C++, thus it may or may not be "dynamic allocation".  It is whatever the compiler vendor who supports this syntax decides it is.

Comment: *Why does this work?* -- [No, it doesn't work](http://rextester.com/BMOLTH93698)

Comment: You are not printing out the array elements. Just a variable you keep setting to the same value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variable length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694199/local-variable-length-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration of variable-length array (VLA) is not standard:

```
int array[arraySize];
```

The reason this line compiles with g++ is that the compiler has provided this functionality as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the declaration exits.

Answer (score 3):

The variable you've declared in this line is called a *variable-length array*:

```
int array[arraySize];
```

Variable-length arrays are a feature of the C programming language, but they're not actually a part of C++. Many compilers support variable-length arrays as a compiler extension (here's the documentation for [the gcc version of variable-length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), for example), but it's not guaranteed that it will work on all compilers.