# what's the difference between vs c++ and mingw c++? why I fail to run this in vs c++?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, mingw

http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-find-closest-pair-points-array/
I can run this without any errors in mingw c++ but with so many errors in visual c++ 2013. why?

Comment: Please describe which steps you took when you attempted to compile the code in Visual C++, and provide a sample of the errors reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, they use two different C/C++ compiler - [Microsoft C/C++ Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) and [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

Your sample use [*Variable-length array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) like here.

```
float closestUtil(Point Px[], Point Py[], int n)
{
    ...
    int mid = n / 2;
    ...
    Point Pyl[mid + 1];
    Point Pyr[n - mid - 1];
    ...
}
```

> Programming languages that support VLAs include Ada, Algol 68 (for non-flexible rows), APL, C99 (although subsequently relegated in C11 to a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support; on some platforms, could be implemented previously with alloca() or similar functions)

-- [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) on wikipedia.org

The Microsoft compiler do not support Variable-length array<sup>[[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx)]</sup> (is not C99 compliant<sup>[[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/ansi-conformance)]</sup>) and GCC support it as and extension<sup>[[7](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length)]</sup>.

To solve this you can replace them with `std::vector`.

You can turn the GCC warnings as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863360/8918119).