# can we give size of static array a variable

Tags: c++, c

hello every one i want to ask that i have read that we can declare dynamic array only by using pointer and using malloc or newlike

```
int * array = new int[strlen(argv[2])];
```

but i have wrote

```
int array[strlen(argv[2])];
```

it gave me no error

i have read that static array can only be declared by giving constant array size but here i have given a variable size to static array

why is it so thanks

---

is it safe to use or is there chance that at any latter stages it will make problem i am using gcc linux

Comment: I have errors. What compiler are you trying this on?

Comment: sir i am using gcc linux and its woking perfectly fine :/

Comment: u can only use const while creating arrays. 
like 
const int size = strlen(argv[2]);
int array[size];

Comment: Apart from the question, sometimes I wonder, how even C99 is handling VLAs ? How can it allocate contiguous memory for the length which is not even known at compile time.

Comment: @iammilind the same way any stack variable is allocated: by subtracting from `ESP`.

Comment: @mainajaved It is an error in VS2010.

Comment: @iammilind: As tenfour says, it's not too hard, and Linux has a non-standard `alloca()` function to do the same (though the scoping is a bit funny I think this sort of construction defies the block scoping and the allocation lives till the end of the *function*). In C this sort of thing can't do much harm because of the "dumb" types. Actually I don't know of any C++ equivalent that allocates dynamically on the stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: Array size at run time w/o dynamic allocation is allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you have is called a *variable-length array* (VLA), and it is not part of C++, although it *is* part of C99. Many compilers offer this feature as an extension.

Even the very new C++11 doesn't include VLAs, as the entire concept doesn't fit well into the advanced type system of C++11 (e.g. what is `decltype(array)`?), and C++ offers out-of-the box library solutions for runtime-sized arrays that are much more powerful (like `std::vector`).

In GCC, compiling with `-std=c++98/c++03/c++0x` and `-pedantic` will give you a warning.

Comment: @mainajaved: It's the latest ISO standard for the C language, from 1999.

Comment: See also [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 5):

C99 support `variable length array`, it defines at [c99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 6.7.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written works in C99. It is a new addition named "variable length arrays". The use of these arrays is often discouraged because there is no interface through which the allocation can fail (`malloc` can return `NULL`, but if a VLA cannot be allocated, the program will segfault or worse, behave erratically).

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[strlen(argv[2])];
```

It is certainly not valid C++ Standard code, as it is defining a variable length array (VLA) which is not allowed in any version of C++ ISO Standard. It is valid only in C99. And in a non-standard versions of C or C++ implementation. GCC provides VLA as an extension, in C++ as well.

So you're left with first option. But don't worry, you don't even need that, as you have even better option. Use `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> array(strlen(argv[2]));
```

Use it.

Comment: sir it gave me no error like i dont understand why... all my concepts are ruined :/

Comment: @mainajaved: As I said, it is provided as extension. If you're using GCC, then compile your program with `-pedantic` option, you will get error.

Comment: ok right thanks sir also sir kindly dive me an example to compile using -pendantic option i didnt find it any where

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers aren't fully C++ standard compliant. What you pointed out is possible in MinGW (iirc), but it's not possible in most other compilers (like Visual C++).

What actually happens behind the scenes is, the compiler changes your code to use dynamically allocated arrays.

I would advice against using this kind of non-standard conveniences.

Comment: I realize that you may be answering the `C++` part of the question and be completely right if the question is considered as such, but for a `C` question, your answer is all wrong. Variable length arrays are standard, are typically allocated on the stack, and Visual C does not support them only because it's not C99-compliant.

Comment: @Pascal You're right. I edited the answer to make it clear I'm talking about C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe. The stack is limited in size, and allocating from it based on user-input like this has the potential to overflow the stack.

For C++, use `std::vector<>`.

Others have answered why it "works".