# C Storage Size Isn't a Constant...why?

Tags: c, size, storage, constants

Here's the simple example program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *hello_string = "Hello";

int main(void)
{
char *world_string = " World";
static char hello_world[strlen(hello_string)+strlen(world_string)];
strcpy(&hello_world[0], hello_string);
strcat(&hello_world[0], world_string);
printf("%s\n", hello_world);
return 0;
}
```

The compiler output:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:13: error: storage size of ‘hello_world’ isn’t constant
static char hello_world[strlen(hello_string)+strlen(world_string)];
            ^
```

I realize the completely useless and unnecessary use of "static" in this case causes the error and with its removal things will compile fine. This is just a simple example to illustrate my question.

What I don't understand is why the storage size is not a constant when the "hello_string" is declared as **const** char * and its size is not going to change during the course of execution. Is this just a case of the compiler not being smart enough to know that?

Comment: Duplicate, see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675399/why-cant-the-size-of-a-static-array-be-made-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` is a function.  It's return value cannot be calculated at compile time.

Comment: Why couldn't the value of `strlen("Hello")` be computed at compile time? It certainly could and moreover a compiler like `gcc` will even actually do this optimization. The problem is C requires here an integer constant expression and the use of a function call disqualifies the expression to be considered constant with the rules of C.

Comment: @ouah Because `strlen` is a function. Depending on how you link the object files, there's no guarantee that it's a function that actually computes the length of the string.  The compiler is not allowed to infer that.

Comment: Then why this code have same error? `static const uint16_t width = 480;static uint16_t tdl[width]={0};`

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler complains about storage size not being constant implicitly means *compile-time constant*, i.e. a value that the compiler can determine at compile-time. The call of `strlen` obviously would happen at runtime, so the compiler cannot know the size of your array.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char hello_string[] = "Hello";

int main(void)
{
    char world_string[] = " World";
    static char hello_world[sizeof hello_string + sizeof world_string];
    strcpy(&hello_world[0], hello_string);
    strcat(&hello_world[0], world_string);
    printf("%s\n", hello_world);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the `static` storage class speficier in your array declaration.

`static` arrays can only have fixed length: i.e., the size of the array has to be an integer constant expression. An expression involving a function call is not a constant expression.

Remove the `static` specifier if you want to use a variable length array. And then don't forget to reserve an extra character in your array for the null terminator.

Comment: Then why this code have same error? `static const uint16_t width = 480;static uint16_t tdl[width]={0};`

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` is a function call. The compiler doesn't know what it does.

Try `sizeof (*hello_string)`. I'm not sure whether that would work.

Or `const char hello_string[] = "Hello"` and `sizeof(hello_string)`, which seems to me more likely to work.

Comment: `sizeof *hello_string` will evaluate to `1`. Also note that `sizeof` isn't a function, so you don't need to do `sizeof(*hello_string)`.