# "Expression must have constant value" CPP

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
int new_length = strlen(string);
char new_string[new_length];
```

So I assumed "new_length" should be constant, so now the code looks like this:

```
const int new_length = strlen(string);
char new_string[new_length];
```

And im still have the same Error.

> "Expression must have constant value"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219712/c-array-expression-must-have-a-constant-value

Comment: @Mat No. its not the same. because here I declared it as constant,

Comment: That variable is const, but its value is determined at runtime. The array length must be a compile-time constant in C++. BTW using `std::string` would probably avoid all those issues.

Comment: @Mat So in C compilers it should work?

Comment: As long as the compiler supports at least C99 or has an extension for that.  They are called VLAs in C.