# Giving the size to an array with a variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been trying to give an array its size through a variable, but it's not working because "must have a constant value".

```
int processes[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int n = sizeof processes / sizeof processes[0];
...
findavgTime(processes, n);

-------------------------------------------------

void findavgTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[])
{
    int wt[n], tat[n]; //These two vars are giving me the error
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219712/c-array-expression-must-have-a-constant-value
check it out, probably it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, you can declare an array with a non-constant size like this. You could, however allocate it dynamically using `new`:

```
int* wt = new int[n];
int* tat = new int[n];
```

Just don't forget that you need to `delete[]` these arrays when you're done.

Comment: Almost no end user actually needs to use `new`. There is `std::vector` instead.

Comment: He wouldn't need to think about deleting, if he'd use a `std::unique_ptr`. But anyhow, like said the standard library has vector for dynamic arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can allocate it on the heap like how Mureinik said, but you can also allocate it on the stack (as you were trying to do) with `alloca()` like this:

```
int* wt = (int*)alloca(n * sizeof(int));
int* tat = (int*)alloca(n * sizeof(int));
```

`free()` should not be called as it is allocated on the stack, not the heap.

Some say using `alloca()` is bad practice because if the call causes a stack overflow, program behavior is undefined. This shouldn't be a problem as long as the array isn't too long.

Comment: You can do this **if** your compiler supports `alloca`. It is not part os standard C++.

Comment: Sure, but **most** (if not all) mainstream compilers support it, I tested nearly all the compilers on Compiler Explorer and it was supported. (MSVC didn't work but I know it supports it.)