# c++ - Expression did not evaluate to a constant/ Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, struct, constants

I wrote the following code on visual studio and it says "expression did not evaluate to a constant" for `[numWashes]` on line 20, however when I try it on other compiler it works, how can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct WashData {
    int membershipStatus;
    int carSize;
    int washType;
    int additionalService;
    double totalCharge;
};


int main() {
    int getNumWashes;
    cout << "Enter the number of car washes: ";
    cin >> getNumWashes;
    const int numWashes = getNumWashes;
    // Create an array of WashData structures
    WashData washes[numWashes]; //line 20 **error**


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `std::vector`: `std::vector<WashData> washes(numWashes);` from the `<vector>` header.

Comment: *on other compiler it works*. That other compiler is accepting code that is not legal C++, this compiler is doing the right thing. In C++ arrays must have constant size. If you want an array like object with variable size use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `WashData washes[numWashes]`, where `numWashes` is a variable is not part of standard C++ at all.   Some C++ compilers support such variable-length arrays (VLAs) as a *non-standard* extension.    You are better off using `std::vector<WashData> washes(numWashes)` which (unlike a VLA) gives you a *resizeable* collection, with initial size `numWashes`.

Comment: I tested your code compiler will prompt E0028, I suggest you refer to the solution in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219712/c-array-expression-must-have-a-constant-value).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a collection of a type of object with a non-compile-time-known size and default-initialize all the entries, then include the `vector` standard header and do `std::vector<WashDate> washes(numWashes);`. Also, I don't see a point in the intermediate `numWashes` variable that just takes the same value as `getNumWashes`.

Comment: Arguably having the intermediate variable allows for `numWashes` to be const.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help. I added getNumWashes because I was trying everything to fix the code, I will delete this variable now.

Comment: @chrysante yes, but I don't see any added value from that.

Comment: @user - Apparently it is an attempt to get a compile time constant, as required for the array declaration. Of course it only creates a runtime constant, so a failed attempt.

Comment: @chrysante -- yes, `numWashes` is `const`, but the size of an array has to be a **compile-time** constant. "You're not allowed to modify this value" is not the same as "this value is known at compile time".

Comment: @PeteBecker I know, see my comment under the original post :)