# Why "Only constants can be used to declare the size of automatic and static arrays"?

Tags: c++, c

> Only constants can be used to declare the size of automatic and static
>   arrays. Not using a constant for this purpose is a compilation error.

Says Pearson.

However, following works fine. According to Pearson, it should not work (I think). Can you help me to understand this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int in;
    cin >> in;
    int a[in];

    a[4] = 412;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<5){
    cout << i << ":" << a[i] << endl;
    i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only applies to C (not C++, C++ doesn't have variable length arrays), and it's because you are using a newer standard and compiler that supports it (if you are using C).

Comment: Works with *with which compiler*?

Comment: This might help, but I can not check without knowing which compiler is being used. You might be able to persuade your compiler to behave like the version of the language that the documentation (Pearson) refers to. For gcc/g++ the command line option `-std=` can be set to a specific language version, e.g. `-std=c++98`. The gcc documentation also recommends using `-pedantic` to get more accurate messages. This might not be exact, but may be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: Array size at run time w/o dynamic allocation is allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an extension to C++ that's found in the GNU compiler, but it doesn't conform to the C++ standard. If you compile your code using `g++ -std=c++98`, the compiler should complain.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using a C++ compiler it works because most of the C++ compilers provide a  compiler extension that supports **[Variable Length arguments(VLA)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)**.

If You are using a C compiler it works because the standard allows it.

---

In C++, VLA are not allowed by the C++ Standard, so any usage of it through compiler extensions will make your code non portable.
C++ provides **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)** or **std::array**(C++11) which satisfy all the requirements using variable length array or c-style arrays resp and you should use them.

Note that,since C99 standard, VLA's are allowed in C.

Always compile your code by selecting a standard in GCC, use one of the options `-ansi`, `-std=c90` or `-std=iso9899:1990`, `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++0x`; to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard.
You should also specify `-pedantic` (or `-pedantic-errors` if you want them to be errors rather than warnings)

Answer (score 0):

These are called variable length arrays. Variable length arrays are only supported in C and only since the C99 standard. Variable length arrays are *not* part of C++ at all, according to *any* standard.

So if this compiles for you, you are either using C99 and up, or as @Philipp said, C++ with an extension that makes your code nonportable and nonconformant to any C++ standard.