# Differences with IDE/compilers array handling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Array size at run time w/o dynamic allocation is allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)

I'm in a class where we have a simple assignment to write a function that returns a pointer to a dynamic array and provide a stub to test it. I have this done so I'm not asking for help with the assignment. On the class blog another student suggests that it is intuitive that one should be able to do `int Array[size];` where `size` is apparently a user defined variable.

I know that in standard C++, at least according to my text, an array must have a "constant integer expression...greater than zero" as a size declarator. Which implies to me that their example **can't** work. In fact, with VS2010 you get three errors when you try. 

However, they explain:

> I know that, you know that, even the g++ compiler in my Ubuntu install
>   AND the Bloodshed compiler on my WinXP install know that. For certain
>   levels of "know that" one would expect "int Array[size];" to work
>   (like it has in both the prior classes).
>
> But evidently it fails to run on some people's VS compilers. One can
>   only assume that, since the common denominator is VS (and yes, I
>   confirmed this by asking a friend to check it on HIS box), that VS is
>   the problem. One of several.

There's already confusion because the `I know that...` part is referring to me telling them that there shouldn't be any reason to `#include <new>` in  order to use `new`, but it seems they think we agree that there shouldn't be any reason to use `new` to allocate a dynamic array.(?)

So the question is obvious. Are there any compilers which will accept `int Array[size];`, where size is not a `const int` without error?

Comment: Look up variable length arrays. Some compilers offer them as an extension. Anyway, there *isn't* any need to use `new`. It's better to just use a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int Array[size];
```

where `size` is not a constant expression is a *variable length array*.  They're a standard feature of C as of the 1999 ISO standard. The C++ standard has not adopted them, but some compilers support them as a language extension.

(Any C++ compiler, when invoked in conforming mode, must at least issue a diagnostic for an array type with a non-constant size.)

Incidentally, this isn't directly related to the IDE you're using; it's controlled by the compiler that your IDE invokes.

As for `#include <new>` there is a standard header by that name, but it's not necessary for the `new` operator, which is built into the language. The `<new>` header provides several overloaded versions of `operator new` and a few other declarations.

Comment: Thanks-I noticed the `new` header and looked at it today. So, would you say using it is a pro/con/indifferent? Variable length arrays that is.

Comment: If you use VLAs in C++, you're limiting the portability of your code to compilers that support it as an extension. If there isn't enough memory to allocate the array, your program's behavior is undefined; there's no way to detect or handle the allocation failure. You're probably better off using the features of the standard C library such as `<vector>`, `<array>` or `<list>`, depending on your requirements.