# array of std::list c

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I can't find any human explaination for this:
how can I create an array of lists like

```
std::list<int> mylist[size] ?
```

If I put this in my program it compiles but creates some problems since it doesn't execute any code (the rest of the code works just fine if I write mylist w/out [size])

I was reading somewhere that using primitive arrays of C is not recommended;
what are the alternatives?

Thanks sorry for newbness

Comment: "*I can't find any human explaination*" - I'll ask my turtle to post an answer :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun lol, I'm your turtle

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are using it?

Comment: C++ alternative to C arrays are … C++ arrays called `std::array`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your declaration is incorrect, and not supported in C++.  You're trying to declare a variable-sized array at run-time, which IS a C99 feature, but is not in C++.  See here: [Array size at run time without dynamic allocation is allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)

You have this:

```
std::list<int> mylist[size]
```

What you need is this:

```
std::list<int> mylist[] = new std::list<int>[size];
```

But this is still a bad idea, as you need to de-allocate it later with `delete []`.  As others have said, you can do it a couple of different ways, all of which are better for c++:

```
std::list< std::list< int > > myListOfLists;      // Linked list of linked lists
std::vector< std::list< int > > myVectorOfLists;  // Better, a vector is more like an array
std::array<std::list<int>, 10> this_would_do;     // From above, only works if you know the array size at compile-time
```

I hope this helps and is clear for you.

Comment: I find `std::list<int> mylist[] = new std::list<int>[size];` cause an error on my MAC machine. However, `std::list<int> *mylist = new std::list<int>[size];` runs smoothly.

Comment: That may be true.  Often a pointer or an empty array in a variable type is the same (compiler-dependent), but obviously not always, and the pointer is probably clearer as to what's "actually happening" on the stack.  Either way, I'd recommend using one of the 3 suggestions at the end (depending on needs) rather than what the OP was asking for, as that's more C++-ish.  If I was given the generic problem of "I need an array of linked lists that I only know the size of at run-time" I'd be using the `std::vector< std::list< TYPE > >` form unless there was another reason.

Answer (score 5):

More specifically,

```
#include <array>
#include <list>

int main() {
     std::array<std::list<int>, 10> this_would_do;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Codes                               // |  Being Human
typedef list<int> L;                  // |  L is now "alias" for list of integers 
const int arr_size=100;               // |  array needs a constant size, list don't
array<L,arr_size> myArrayOfList;      // |  An Array as elements L
list<L> myListOfList;                //  |  A List of elements L 

//A STL list is doubly linked list
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) can be a good alternative to C array:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<std::list<int> > vectorOfLists;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a fixed size (e.g. you are having lists of items that have been given a "score" of 0-9), then using a fixed size array is perfectly fine:

```
std::list<item> scored_items[10];
```

Of course, it's a poor idea if you don't know beforehand how many you actually want. Then either `std::list < std::list < item > > myLists;` or a vector `std::vector < std::list < item> my_lists;` would be suitable solutions.

The "correct" solution depends on what your ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to declare a list is as follows

```
std::list<T> my_list;
```

T is a placeholder for any type, including another list, so you can replace T with `std::list<int>` which gives the following

```
std::list<std::list<int>> my_list;
```

That declares a list that can hold lists that can hold integers. Note that some compilers may complain about `>>`, in that case change it to `> >`

Comment: a `std::vector` would be more appropriate. Even known in OPs case a `std::vector<int>` over a `std::list<int>` would have *probably* been better in the first place.