# Why my program is failing for large input? more than 10^5

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming.i'm trying to solve the following question :

**Problem Introduction :**
You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with the current number
x: multiply x by 2, multiply x by 3, or add 1 to x. Your goal is given a positive integer n, find the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.

**Task** 
Given an integer n, compute the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n
starting from the number 1.
The input consists of a single integer 1  < n < 10^6.

**code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
void primitive_calculator(int number)
{
    std::vector<int> min_steps(number+1,INT_MAX);
    std::list<int> path[number+1];
    min_steps[0]=0; min_steps[1]=0;
    path[0].push_back(0);
    path[1].push_back(1);
    for (int i=2 ; i<=number ; i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
        {
            if(min_steps[i/3] < min_steps[i])
            {
                min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/3]+1;
                path[i]=path[i/3];
                path[i].push_back(i);
            }
        }
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            if( min_steps[i/2] < min_steps[i])
            {
                min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/2]+1;
                path[i]=path[i/2];
                path[i].push_back(i);
            }
        }

        if( min_steps[i-1] < min_steps[i])
        {
             min_steps[i]=min_steps[i-1]+1;
             path[i]=path[i-1];
             path[i].push_back(i);
        }
    }
    std::cout<<min_steps[number]<<"\n";
    while(!path[number].empty())
    {
        std::cout<<path[number].front()<<" ";
        path[number].pop_front();
    }

}
int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin>>number;
    primitive_calculator(number);
    return 0;
}
```

This program is failing for input number greater than 10^5 .Why so?
And how can i improve the code?

Comment: It may be due to the data type int. Try using long int or long long int for bigger numbers!

Comment: I don't know,  why your program even working for value less than 10^5. Consider the value of `i=2` then  your are doing `if (min_steps[i/2] < min_steps[i])`. And `min_steps[2]` is not defined.

Comment: What is `std::list<int> path[number+1]`?

Comment: @Shravan40 std::vector<int> min_steps(number+1,INT_MAX); creates a vector of size (number+1) and initialised to INT_MAX.

Comment: @Mine std::list<int> path[number+1] ...it is an array of lists?
i am going to save the path to each number in this list.So (number+1) lists for (number+1) ,like path[10] will store the path to reach number 10 that is {1,3,9,10} . Can you suggest something else ? better?

Comment: should the body of your `for` loop be `if {...} if {...}  {...}` or `if{...} else if{...} else{...}` ? since it looks like that last block of yours is executed every time the `for` loop sweeps through.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the edit. I think I understand your algorithm now. Clever. Note: `std::list<int> path[number + 1]` is illegal, I think. Since you cannot declare array with variable length. Should consider `new`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897943/array-of-stdlist-c

Comment: What exactly is the number input that your program breaks down? I tried 999999 and it works

Comment: @Tuan333 It's an assignment question on coursera so test cases are hidden .I was trying for random inputs & it was not working for anything greater than 10^5 (was getting primitive_calculator stopped working or program ended abruptly ) but on changing std::list<int> path[number+1]; to  std::list<int64_t>* path=new std::list<int64_t>[number+1]; 
it's working  now and accepted on coursera .Thanks

Comment: Consider using a vector of lists, instead.

Comment: The current code doesn't look very "dynamic" to me. You should have a data structure that is answering the following questions: Given current value `x` and target value `n`, is any result available? ... (if available) what is the minimum number of operations to reach `n` from `x`? ... (if available, optionally) what is the next operation on `x` to reach `n` with the least amount of steps? ... (if not available) compute the intermediate result. I think you are currently computing to much garbage with your loop.

Comment: One improvement would be to go backwards from the given number and work your way to 1. Lots of numbers will not be even considered then.

Comment: Please note that the goal is not to display the path, but only the number of steps in the path. The actual efficient algorithm would not build the path in the loop `[2..n]`, but would deal with all the numbers that require current number of steps in the loop `[1..step]`. In each iteration you would have a set of numbers that can be reached in that many steps, and from that set you build another set of numbers that can be reached in one more step.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is on line:

```
std::list<int> path[number+1];
```

1. It creates an array of `std::list` variable on **stack**, so if the number is huge, the stack overflows and gets segment fault.
2. This code gets warning from GCC:

   > warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'path' [-Wvla]
3. It is rejected by clang as well:

   > error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'std::list'

So do **NOT** define huge variables **on stack**.

Instead, what you should do is use `std::vector`, e.g. change the line to:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> path(number+1);
```

Then your problem is solved.