# Is the size of an array determined at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays

When I was reading about the array initialization in [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/). I found out this note.

```
type name [elements];
```

> NOTE: The elements field within square brackets `[]`, representing the number of elements in the array, must be a constant expression, since arrays are blocks of static memory whose size must be determined at compile time, before the program runs.*

As I know array allocate the memory in the run time. This should be a false note? or what does it means?

Comment: No, the note is correct and clear. It doesn't say that anything gets *allocated* at compile time. It says that the size is *defined* at compile time. The actual array will be allocated at runtime, using the size defined at compile time

Comment: If you tried it with a run-time **variable** providing the value for `elements` and it "worked" you're using a compiler that supports VLAs in C++ (such a gcc). And though it may "work", it isn't standard. The note is accurate. If you want runtime-sizing, use a `std::vector<>` and heap-managed data.

Comment: You seem to be confusing statically allocated arrays (`int foo[sz];`) with dynamically allocated arrays (`int *foo = new foo[sz]`).  The former must have its size known at compile time; the latter can have its size determined at runtime.

Comment: Ok, Got what does it means. but what is the reason that stack array allocation strictly to static allocation in C++ standards?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: Becuase there's `std::vector<>` in C++, which is often a better alternative. (There's also `std::array<Type, Count>` which is stored like `Type[Count]` but has `.size(), .begin(), .end() `  etcetera)

Answer (score 6):

Please check if the following answers help in giving you clarity about this.

[Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array)

Static arrays are created on the stack, and necessarily have a fixed size (the size of the stack needs to be known going into a function):
    int foo[10];

Dynamic arrays are created on the heap. They can have any size, but you need to allocate and free them yourself since they're not part of the stack frame:
    int* foo = new int[10];
    delete[] foo;

You don't need to deal with the memory management of a static array, but they get destroyed when the function they're in ends

[Array size at run time without dynamic allocation is allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)

C99 standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) supports variable sized arrays on the stack. Some of the compilers might implement these standards and support variable sized arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `T a[N]` requires that `N` be a [converted constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

> Converted constant expression is an expression implicitly converted to
>   prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core constant
>   expression. If the literal constant expression has class type, it is
>   contextually implicitly converted to the expected integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type with a constexpr user-defined conversion function.

An int literal such as `5` is a prvalue, so can be used in the declaration `T a[5]`, but an lvalue, for example `int n = 5` cannot be used in the declaration `T a[n]`, unless the lvalue under-goes an [implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) where the lvalue:

> a) has integral or enumeration type, is non-volatile const, and is
>   initialized with a constant expression, or an array of such (including
>   a string literal)
>
> b) has literal type and refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr or to its non-mutable subobject
>
> c) has literal type and refers to a non-volatile temporary, initialized with a constant expression

Therefore the following are valid:

```
const int n = 5; 
int a[n]; 
constexpr int n = 5; 
int a[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use :

```
int array[42];
```

but not

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int array[n]; // Not standard C++
```

the later is supported as extension by some compiler as VLA (Variable length array)