# c++:Hackerank:Error in taking input

Tags: c++, c99

This is a part of my question.I tried many times but couldn't get the answer

**Problem Statement**

You are given a list of N people who are attending ACM-ICPC World Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know. And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of topics.

Note Suppose a, b, and c are three different people, then (a,b) and (b,c) are counted as two different teams.

**Input Format**

The first line contains two integers, N and M, separated by a single space, where N represents the number of people, and M represents the number of topics. N lines follow.
Each line contains a binary string of length M. If the ith line's jth character is 1, then the ith person knows the jth topic; otherwise, he doesn't know the topic.

**Constraints**

```
2≤N≤500 
1≤M≤500
```

**Output Format**

On the first line, print the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know. 
On the second line, print the number of 2-person teams that can know the maximum number of topics.

**Sample Input**

```
4 5
10101
11100
11010
00101
```

**Sample Output**

```
5
2
```

**Explanation**

(1, 3) and (3, 4) know all the 5 topics. So the maximal topics a 2-person team knows is 5, and only 2 teams can achieve this.

**this is a a part of my work.Any clue how can i get this to work**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>  
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m, max = 0, max1 = 0, count = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;                                 //for input of N and M
    int a[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)         //for input of N integers of digit size M
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j + >>
        cin >> a[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            max = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k<m; k++)
            {
                if (a[i][k] == 1 || a[j][k] == 1) max++;
                cout << k;
                if (k = m - 1 && max>max1) max1 = max;
                if (k == m - 1 && max == max1) count++;;

            }
        }
    }

    cout << max1 << endl << count;
    return 0;
}
```

I think the way of taking my input logic is wrong.could you please help me out.I am stuck in this question from 5 days.
PLease only help me on how should i take input and how to read the digit of integer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed

Comment: You cannot do this `cin>>n>>m;`, then `int a[n][m];`, the array size must be know at compile time, not run time.

Comment: then how should i take input in this question?

Comment: You can make a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: but sir how will i read digit of integer specifically and the array size issue of decalaring its size at compile time is valid in c99

Comment: C99 is not C++. More fun, I believe that trick is only optional in more recent C standards.

Comment: `if (k = m - 1 && max>max1) max1 = max;` you sure you don't want `k == m - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a compiler with me so there's probably a syntax boner or two in there, but the logic walks through on paper.

Builds the storage:

```
std::cin >> n >> m; //for input of N and M
std::vector<std::vector<bool>>list(n,std::vector<bool>(m, false));
```

Loads the storage:

```
char temp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //for input of N integers of digit size M
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        std::cin >> temp;
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            list[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Runs the algorithm

```
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    for (int b = a+1; b < n; b++)
    {
        int knowcount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (list[a][j] | list[b][j])
            {
                knowcount ++;
            }
        }
        if (knowcount > max)
        {
            groupcount = 1;
            max = know;
        }
        else if(knowcount == max)
        {
            groupcount ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of input is wrong. According to your method, the input will have to be given like this (with spaces between individual numbers):

```
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
```

Only then it makes sense to create a matrix. But since the format in the question does not contain any space between a number in the same row, thus this method will fail. Taking into consideration the test case, you might be tempted to store the 'N' numbers in a single dimensional integer array, but keep in mind the constraints ('M' can be as big as 500 and int or even unsigned long long int data type cannot store such a big number).

Comment: Don't think of 10101 as the first input. It is a stream. `cin >>char` will read exactly one character from that stream, skipping and discarding all of the usual whitespace characters. Repeated `cin >> char` will continue to extract characters one at a time. Wrap `while (std::cin >> temp) cout <<temp; `in a little quickie program and watch what happens as you type.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, you were right. I did not know this. But, the way Hammad has taken input, it's wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's wrong. The whole line, or as much as the int can eat without causing the conversion to fail, will be read in as one integer.