# c++ expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this method:

```
void createSomething(Items &items)
{
    int arr[items.count]; // number of items
}
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
expression must have a constant value
```

I found just this solution:

```
int** arr= new int*[items.count];
```

so I'm asking is there a better way how do handle this?

Comment: Your "solution" does something quite different to what you were intending to do in the first sample. Anyway, look into `std::vector`.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear to you already, you can't declare an array where the size of the array is determined at run time using the bracket notation.  There are other ways of handling this (see malloc() ), but as @juanchopanza pointed out std::vector is the way to go.

Comment: I think you need to see that the correct version of you "solution" would be `int* arr = new int[items.count];` not using an array of pointers. but of course `std::vector` is better

Comment: What are you trying to do....?

Comment: I just wanted to create the array, but don't worry already got an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `std::vector`

```
void createSomething(Items &items)
{
    std::vector<int> arr(items.count); // number of items
}
```

The reason your first method won't work is that the size of an array must be know at compile time ([without using compiler extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed)), so you have to use dynamically sized arrays. You can use `new` to allocate the array yourself

```
void createSomething(Items &items)
{
    int* arr = new int[items.count]; // number of items

    // also remember to clean up your memory
    delete[] arr;
}
```

But it is safer and IMHO more helpful to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: If I use std::vector I don't have to clean up memory?

Comment: No you do not, the destructor for `std::vector` will clean up the memory itself, which is one reason why it is nicer to use than managing the memory by hand.

Answer (score 2):

`Built in arrays` & `std::array` always require a constant integer to determine their size. Of course in case of `dynamic arrays` (the one created with `new` keyword) can use a non-constant integer as you have shown.

However `std::vector` (which of course internally a dynamic array only) uses a is the best solution when it comes to `array-type applications`. It's not only because it can be given a non-constant integer as size but also it can grown as well as dynamically quite effectively. Plus `std::vector` has many fancy functions to help you in your job.

In your question you have to simply replace `int arr[items.count];` with :-

```
std::vector<int> arr(items.count);   // You need to mention the type
// because std::vector is a class template, hence here 'int' is mentioned
```

Once you start with `std::vector`, you would find yourself preferring it in 99% cases over normal arrays because of it's flexibility with arrays. First of all you needn't bother about deleting it. The vector will take care of it. Moreover functions like `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, `emplace`, `erase`, etc help you make effective insertions & deletions to it which means you don't have to write these functions manually.

For more reference refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)