# Negative array index and seemingly redundant template usage

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compiler-errors

I came across these lines of code:

```
template< int I > struct arg
{
    arg()
    {
    }

    template< class T > arg( T const & /* t */ )
    {
        // static assert I == is_placeholder<T>::value
        typedef char T_must_be_placeholder[ I == is_placeholder<T>::value? 1: -1 ];
    }
};

template< class T > struct is_placeholder
{
    enum _vt { value = 0 };
};
```

What could be the reason the struct `is_placeholder` is templated while typename `T` is not used anywhere inside?

Why `T_must_be_placeholder` is defined in such a way so that it can have invalid size `-1`. To realise this, I called `arg<1>(1)` and it gave `error: size of array is negative` as expected.  Is it some sort of *sanity-check technique*? Why doesn't the compiler report this issue if the `arg<1>(1)` call is not made?

While

```
int i = 0;
char a[i == 1 ? 1 : -1]; //No error
```

*If sanity check works for 1st example, then how does it fail for second one?*

Comment: This is a poor man's implementation of static_assert. If some condition is not met, an array of negative size is declared, which triggers a compilation error.

Comment: Your last example should not compile, because the size of the array is not a constant expression. It probably does because of a GCC extension, not sure what  happens if you pass a negative size.

Comment: Surprisingly, this does compile http://ideone.com/LrWvHh. Check out.

Answer (score 0):

`is_placeholder` is a template so that it can be specialized for different `T`. Say I create a struct `example` and want `is_placeholder<example>::value` to be 42. I would do this:

```
struct example {};

template< class T > struct is_placeholder
{
    enum _vt { value = 0 };
};

template<>
struct is_placeholder<example>
{
    enum _vt { value = 42 };
};

template< int I > struct arg
{
    arg()
    {
    }

    template< class T > arg( T const & /* t */ )
    {
        // static assert I == is_placeholder<T>::value
        typedef char T_must_be_placeholder[ I == is_placeholder<T>::value ? 1: -1 ];
    }
};

void test()
{
    auto x = arg<42>(example()); // compiles
    auto y = arg<43>(example()); // assertion
    return 0;
}
```

In this case `T_must_be_placeholder` checks if `is_placeholder<example>::value` (which we just specialized to be 42) is the same as `I`. So if `I` is 42 it compiles, but if `I` is anything else, it won't.

Attempting to create an array with negative size is a way of deliberately preventing the code from compiling, so yes, this is probably a sanity check (static assertion, as it says in the comment).

Comment: About why `is_placeholder` is templated? Sorry I am little inexperienced in using templates. :|

Comment: Why does not `int i = 0; char a[i == 1 ? 1 : -1];` fail then?

Comment: @SauravSahu because then you have VLA (a gcc extension for arrays with size known at runtime). make i const and you get an error

Comment: I suspect because `i` isn't statically known that this causes a variable size array to be allocated on the stack at runtime rather than a compilation error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed

Comment: @user634175 your suspicion is correct, if by "statically known" you meant "known at compile time" :p

Comment: @bolov indeed I did, may the pedantry police take me away :) -- incidentally `constexpr int i = 0; char a[i == 1 ? 1 : -1];` works!

Comment: @user634175 Already called them. Fortunately for you they don't take my calls anymore...

Comment: @user634175 `const int i = 0` is enough for it to work