# How does (*prt)[N][N] work when dealing with heap allocation memory?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc, c99

Today a colleague at work showed me a way of declaring a 2D array in such a way that I can allocate it linearly but still use 2D square bracket (`[][]`) notation to access elements.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 2

int main () {
  int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE] = malloc (sizeof (int) * SIZE * SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      (*a)[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  (*a)[0][1] = 100;

  /* should yield:
   *   0
   *   100
   *   0
   *   0
   */
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      printf ("%d\n", (*a)[i][j]);
    }
  }

  free (a);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is in contrast to computing the index and then perform pointer arthimetic (e.g. `*(a + (x * SIZE + y))` or more tersly `a[x * SIZE + y]`) to access an element.

The critical part is the shape declaration of the pointer `x` (e.g. `(*x)[][]`), which seems to encode this information as a type for the value that `x` points to.

Beyond this though I do not understand how this works. What does this notation exactly doing? Is it syntactic sugar? It looks symilar to dynamic stack allocation for arrays (see [Array size at run time without dynamic allocation is allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737240/1203078) as one example of this), but clearly this allocation is happening on the heap.

I've looked for more information about this notation/declaration of the pointer but can't find much other than the term *element type* coming up - but I'm not certain that this is related.

EDIT #1:

I should have mentioned this question is in the context of using the heap, and not the stack. I'm aware of stack based dynamic allocation of arrays, but the work I'm doing specifically looks at dynamic memory allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE]
```

declares `a` as a pointer to a `SIZE` by `SIZE` array of `int` - assuming `SIZE == 3`, you get something like this:

```
   +---+          +---+---+---+
a: |   | -------> |   |   |   |
   +---+          +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
```

(actually, layout would be strictly linear, but we'll go with this representation for now).

To access any element of the pointed-to array, we'd write `(*a)[i][j]` - we have to dereference `a` explicitly, since we don't want to index into `a`, we want to index into what `a` *points to*.

Remember that `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` elements (not bytes!) from that address and deference the result.  Thus, `(*a)[i][j]` is equivalent to `a[0][i][j]`.

Now, if `a` points to a 3x3 array of `int`, then `a + 1` points to the *next 3x3 array* of `int`:

```
   +---+          +---+---+---+
a: |   | -------> |   |   |   |
   +---+          +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
a + 1: ---------> |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  +---+---+---+
```

which we would access as `(*(a + 1))[i][j]`, or simply `a[1][i][j]`.

Now, why use a pointer to an array in the first place?  In this case we're dynamically allocating the array, which we would do if a) we didn't know how many `SIZExSIZE` arrays we'd need until runtime, or b) if the resulting array would be too large to allocate as an `auto` variable, or c) if we want to extend or shrink the number of `SIZExSIZE` arrays as necessary.

How does this method of allocating a multidimensional array work?  Let's start by allocating an `N`-element array of `T`:

```
T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

`sizeof *arr` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`, so we're setting aside space for `N` objects of type `T`.

Now let's replace `T` with an array type, `R [M]`:

```
R (*arr)[M] = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

`sizeof *arr` is equivalent to `sizeof (R [M])`, so we're setting aside space for `N` objects of type `R [M]` - IOW, `N` `M`-element arrays of `R`.  We've dynamically created the equivalent of `R a[M][N]`.

We could also have written this as

```
R (*arr)[M] = malloc( sizeof (R) * M * N );
```

although I prefer using `sizeof *arr`; you'll see why in a second.

Now, we can replace `R` with *yet another* array type, `S [L]`:

```
S (*arr)[L][M] = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

`sizeof *arr` is equivalent to `sizeof (S [L][M])`, so we're allocating enough space for `N` objects of type `S [L][M]`, or `N` `L` by `M` arrays of `S`.  We've dynamically created the equivalent of `S arr[L][M][N]`.

The semantics for dynamically allocating 1D, 2D, and 3D arrays are *exactly the same* - all that's changed is the type. By using `sizeof *arr` each time, I only need to track how many elements I need of that type.

Comment: thanks for that, this is very clear answer - by changing my type from `T [M][N]` to `T [M]` and allocating with `sizeof (*arr)` I no longer need to dereference the pointer - really makes the code a lot more understandable/neat.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong but not the more usual (and idiomatic way). To declare a dynamic array of size N, you use: `int *arr = malloc(N * sizeof(int));`. In fact this declares `arr` as *a pointer to the first element of an array of N int*. A 2D array is an array of arrays so to declare an 2D array N*N, the more common way is :

```
int (*arr)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
```

This actually declares `arr` as a pointer to the first element of N arrays of N int. You can then normally use `arr[i][j]`.

So what is that amazing `int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE] = malloc (sizeof (int) * SIZE * SIZE);`?

You declare arr as a pointer to the first (and single) element of an array of 2D arrays NxN of integers. The good news is that the declaration is explicit for the size of all dimensions, but the downside is that you must consistently dereference it: `(*arr)[i][j]` which is not different *per definition of the `[]` operator in C* from `arr[0][i][j]`.

It is nothing more than my own opinion, but I strongly urge you to stick to the first method. That first and single element trick is likely to disturb any future reader or maintainer of your code because it is not idiomatic.

Comment: Actually I would say that `int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE]` is the most correct declaration, but it is just not very practical to use.

Answer (score 0):

What `int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE] = malloc (sizeof (int) * SIZE * SIZE);` does is declaring a pointer to a two-dimensional array of integers. This would only be useful when you purposely want to allocate the space in the heap instead of in the stack (for example, if the dimensions of the array are unknown at compile time) You would then dereference the pointer and access it as you would with a normal two-dimensional array.

You could skip the dereferencing step by declaring your variable as an array of pointers, each one of them pointing to a standard array of integers `int *a[SIZE]`, or even as `int **a`. In both cases you could access any value using bracket notation `a[x][y]` without needing to dereference `a` before.

If you know the dimensions of the array prior at compilation time, and don't need to allocate it in the heap, you can just declare the array like this:

```
int a[SIZE][SIZE];
```

which is both shorter and more efficient as it allocates the space in the stack.

You can always access an array using `[][]`. <s>You have to keep in mind that everything in C works with memory address offsets. When you have an integer array declared as `int a[4]` and you access it with square brackets like this `a[3]` you're telling the processor to take the memory address of `a` and apply an offset of `3 * sizeof(int)`. You could access the same element by using `*(&a + 3)`, or even with `3[a]`, as taking the address and adding the offset is the same as taking the offset and adding the address.</s>

So when you use `a[2][3]`, the compiler is doing exactly the same as above, only with more dimensions. So you don't need to do `a[x * SIZE + y]` because that's exactly what the compiler is doing for you when you do `a[x][y]`.

**EDIT: as some pointed out in the comments, actually pointers don't necessarily store a memory reference, altough that's definitely the most common implementation.**

I hope my explanation was clear.

Comment: There may be various reasons why heap allocation is needed though. For example, in most OS you should avoid allocating large objects on the stack, to prevent stack overflow. That being said, your answer doesn't really explain what the code in the question does.

Comment: @Lundin I think that's not the issue was having though. It appeared to me that he was just trying to access a multi-dimensional array without doing pointer arithmetic, which is perfectly possible with both stack and heap allocated arrays.

Comment: This answer misses the point. The code in the question was only an example. To be clearer, it should have taken the array size from some dynamic value instead of a constant defined with the preprocessor. But the intent was to address situations where the memory is dynamically allocated and the size is not known at compile time. Additionally, it is not strictly true that C works with “memory address offsets.” The C standard defines behavior with an abstract mdoel, and the implementation may use other means of accomplishing the required results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right, I was missing the point. I edited my question to better address it. You're wrong about the address offset thing though, pointers are by definition references to a memory address, and the C standard definers behavior for the subscript operator like this: "The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))."

Comment: @dieortin ...where the result of *(E1 + E2) is a de-referenced pointer, not an address. If either E1 or E2 was an address, the code would obviously break, it it would then need to do arithmetic on bytes rather than pointed-at types.

Comment: @dieortin: The C standard defines a pointer type to be a reference to an entity of the referenced type, not a memory address: “A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.” (C 2011 N1570 6.2.5 20.) You have likely been taught about pointers using memory addresses as examples, but a flat memory address space is just one possible implementation of the abstraction defined by the C standard. There are others.

Answer (score 0):

`int (*a)[SIZE][SIZE]` is an *array pointer* to an array of type `int[SIZE][SIZE]`. This is a special kind of pointer that is used to point at whole arrays, but otherwise works like any other pointer. So when you write `(*a)[i][j]` you say "give me the contents of the pointer (the 2D array), then in those contents give me item number [i][j]".

But since array pointers behave like other pointers, you can use it point to the first element instead of the whole 2D array. (Just like you can use `int*` to point at the first item of an `int[n]` array.) This is done using the trick of omitting the left-most dimension: `int (*a)[SIZE] = ...`. This now points to the first 1D array in the array of arrays. And now you can use it as `a[i][j]` instead, which is far more readable and convenient.

Array pointers, the above trick, and how to use them to dynamically allocate 2D arrays as one single chunk of memory is all addressed in my answer to [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Actually there's no such thing as an "array pointer". All pointers are just memory addresses, with a type that lets you do some things like work with indexes instead of doing pointer arithmetic by hand.

Comment: Also, there's no way to "point to the whole 2D array", as again pointers are just memory addresses. The closest thing to doing that is just pointing to the first element, which C does.

Comment: @dieortin Rather, there is no such thing as memory addresses in the C language, the standard lacks that concept. If you scroll down in the linked answer you'll find an example of how to do arithmetic with array pointers. You can think of an array pointer as pointing at the whole object, since C disallows code such as `int (*a)[1]; int (*b)[2] = a;`.